# No print output in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a program which runs fine, but I get no print output even though I have a NSLog file in main.m Can you tell me what's wrong? Thank you.

main.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Stockholding.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

  @autoreleasepool {

    StockHolding *stockA;
    StockHolding *stockB;
    StockHolding *stockC;

    [stockA setPurchaseSharePrice:2.40];
    [stockA setCurrentSharePrice:3.12];
    [stockA setNumberOfShares:40];

    [stockB setPurchaseSharePrice:1.50];
    [stockB setCurrentSharePrice:1.41];
    [stockC setNumberOfShares:35];

    [stockC setPurchaseSharePrice:1.10];
    [stockC setCurrentSharePrice:1.20];
    [stockC setNumberOfShares:60];


    NSArray *holdings = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:stockA, stockB, stockC, nil];

    for (StockHolding *n in holdings) {
      // Call the methods
      float cost = [n costInDollars];
      float value = [n valueInDollars];
      NSLog(@"Bought stock for $%.2f, It is now at $%.2f, I have %d shares, They cost me $%.2f, Now they are worth $%.2f", [n purchaseSharePrice], [n currentSharePrice], [n numberOfShares], cost, value);
    }
  }
    return 0;
}
```

StockHolding.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface StockHolding : NSObject {
  float purchaseSharePrice;
  float currentSharePrice;
  int numberOfShares;
}

@property float purchaseSharePrice;
@property float currentSharePrice;
@property int numberOfShares;

-(float)costInDollars;
-(float)valueInDollars;

@end
```

StockHolding.m

```
#import "StockHolding.h"

@implementation StockHolding

@synthesize purchaseSharePrice, currentSharePrice, numberOfShares;

-(float)costInDollars
{
  return (purchaseSharePrice * numberOfShares);
}

-(float)valueInDollars
{
  return (currentSharePrice * numberOfShares);
}

@end
```

Comment: If you place a `NSLog` instruction outside the loop does it get printed?

Comment: Have you verified with a breakpoint that the NSLog is called?

Comment: No. If I move it outside the loop, then the compiler doesn't recognize the n variable because it's local.

Comment: I put a breakpoint where I initialized the array, and then stepped into the code. For some reason it seems to jump over the loop (not execute the loop), then directly goes to the closing brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't actually created any of those `StockHolding` objects. Thus, your array is empty, and the loop doesn't do anything.

```
StockHolding *stockA;
```

is just a declaration of a pointer. You need to create the object to which it points; the usual procedure is this:

```
StockHolding *stockA = [[StockHolding alloc] init];
```

Since, under ARC, object pointers are initialized to `nil` (which means "no object"), you are passing `nil` as all of the arguments to `arrayWithObjects:`. `nil` being the sentinel value meaning "there are no more arguments", the array is created without contents.

With an empty array, `for (StockHolding *n in holdings)` doesn't have anything to enumerate over, so none of the code in the body of the loop, including your `NSLog()`, gets executed.

Comment: OK, thank you. Initialized the objects, and now it works fine. Thanks again!